# Correct table: ad_status or ad_statues?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How's everyone? Well?

So, my problem is: I'll using "cake bake" for generate "MVC" for me, right?
So... I have a table (mysql):

```
// ad = ads 
ad_status
```

I think the name is correct:

```
ad = ads
status = status of ads
```

But the cake say the correct name is:

```
ad_statues
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cake's table naming convention dictates that table names should be plural.

Therefore I think it should actually be `ad_statuses` or `ad_states` (Wiktionary suggests the plural is indeed `statuses`).

I think `statues` is either a typo or Cake is failing to correctly inflect `status`.

NB - it doesn't really matter what your tables are called; but going with the convention/what Cake says means you can take advantage of a lot of automagic.

Personally I'd go with `ad_statuses`.

Comment: Ok, but.... when I try create the table "ads" and add column "ad_status_id", CakePHP say: Error: Missing database table 'ads_temporaries' for model 'AdsTemporary'. What is this?